# PostgreSQL ERROR: Could not load library postgis-2.1.dll

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using pgAdmin III to connect to my PostgreSQL database (Postgres) and I'm trying to add an extension to the database which is Postgis.

Even though the "missing" file is in the folder the following message error shows:

> "ERROR: Could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostGreSQL/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.dll": unknown error 193."

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How did you install PostGIS?

Comment: With the Application Stack Builder (Windows)

Comment: Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The windows version is not mentioned. With win 7 check wether postgis is installed. Remove it. From http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/ get the right postgis installer and install new, then start in pgadmin with 'create extension postgis;'.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error "unknown error 193" occured since I installed a 64-bit version of PostgreSQL but tried to use the 32-bit version of PostGIS (somewhere I read that the 64-bit version would not work properly, but that was in 2011 and now it does).

For me it finally worked when I:
1. removed the existing PostGIS installation (Control Panel -> Programs) 
2. shutdown the PostgreSQL service
3. installed the 64-bit version of PostGIS (2.1.3, Postgre in 9.3)
4. restarted the PostgreSQL service
5. installed the extension via PgAdmin III